# Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 28

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am getting an error of:

Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 28

when I try to bulk load my data having about 1400 rows. When I copy paste first few rows (even as much as 31), the bulk insert works fine.

Here is my bulk insert code:

```
BULK INSERT Try
FROM 'c:\try.psv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR ='|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure it was something got to do with hidden \r before \n or something as when I copy pasted all 1400 rows in a new file it worked alright...

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* We don't know, we can't run your statement, nor do we know the definition of your data or the contents of your file. The error, however, *is* telling you the problem. You have a truncation error.

Comment: So what is row 1 col 28?
Sounds like the error may be a red herring, you need a process of elimination to start with a smaller working file and gradually add to it until you encounter the error.

Comment: col 28 is the last column. As I stated copy  paste of first few rows worked though it is choking on first row. But again copy paste of all rows also worked. I also tried ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n' which did not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPENROWSET instead of Bulk insert. Either way, if you can provide the data file  then I can try this and post some answers.